# Isn't displaying the number of upvotes when reviewing close votes biasing?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

The question of whether a question should be closed or not is partially/mostly orthogonal to whether than question merits an "upvote" outside of SO. e.g. a question could be really bad, but within the scope of SO, or a great question about, say, workplace dynamics which belongs at programmers.SE . However, when you're asked to review close votes, you see the question's number of upvotes. I think that might be biasing reviewers for or against questions based on a mostly-invalid criterion.

Actually, even if the number of upvotes were valid, you would want reviewers to consider the question on the merits rather than follow the herd.

So, I suggest the option be considered to not display the number of upvotes as part of the close vote review page.

Comment: Imo, users should be checking the original question, any way. It could provide some context that the CV review can't. That said, the votes it has has no relevance.